# What mathematical tool is similar to a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, object, math

I am trying to write documentation on a piece of Javascript code but I am having trouble describing the objects made by the code in a concise and understandable way. It is especially difficult because the objects have nested objects (often multiple layers).
Is there any mathematics that involves things with keys and attached values?

If not, how best can I describe an object with multiple nest objects in a concise manner?

Note: Just showing an example of an object is not enough as the structure changes often. Also, there are mathematical relationships between the keys and the values (coupon dates as keys and coupon payments as values).

Comment: I'd say a Set. Or rather a set of sets. But sets aren't really easy to understand either. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)

Comment: I saw a comment on it earlier, JavaScript objects pretty much follow the [associative array abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), which is a mathematical concept by virtue since computer science is basically a subset of applied mathematics, but if you need a true mathematical representation there's [relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) which was created for relational databases (close enough) and is essentially an extension of set theory... just remember math doesn't necessarily mean it's clear and concise

Comment: Have you considered a modeling language, e.g., UML? You can use UML to produce graphical class and object diagrams, etc., to show whatever relationships you like.

Comment: "*mathematical relationships between the keys and the values, like coupon dates as keys and coupon payments as values*" - that sounds much more like *semantic* relationship. But if you really want to model it by math, that's a [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) indeed.

Comment: @Bergi By mathematical relationship, I mean coupon payments are a function of the coupon date (time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I saw a comment on it earlier, JavaScript objects pretty much follow the associative array abstract data type, which is a mathematical concept by virtue since computer science is basically a subset of applied mathematics, but if you need a true mathematical representation there's relational algebra which was created for relational databases (close enough) and is essentially an extension of set theory... just remember math doesn't necessarily mean it's clear and concise – Patrick Barr yesterday

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Javascript objects are **functions** or **mappings**, in that they map keys to values.

Beyond that, it is hard to compare... the domain can encompass numbers, and a subset of all strings. As simple as that is to say, I'm not sure what mathematical field (etc) the domain would be equivalent to!

The range would, of course, be worse, as values in the range can be numbers, strings, booleans, undefined, further objects, or functions. However, I think the concept of an object being a **mapping** is fairly intuitive.

This doesn't include the prototype style inheritance, but I'm not sure how deep you want to go...